# When to use vector clock for distributed system?

Tags: python, performance, cloud, distributed-transactions

When to use vector clock for distributed system ? It will be great if explained with some example

Answer (score 0):

A vector clock is a data structure used for determining the partial ordering of events in a distributed system and detecting causality violations, were you can have currently events, and a huge amount of them.

[image: For example we can see this image]

If you need to know what event triggered an error, violation or situation, in your distributed system, this is the appropriate data structure.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this will help